# How to remove database namespace from generated sqls from EF4.1 code-first when using Oracle?

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying Entity Framework 4.1 Code-first with the new oracle provider.

I've created a simple object to insert into the database but I'm getting an insert error.
Looking at the tracers I find the sql:

```
insert into "dbo"."TB_TEST"("STR_NAME", "DT_HR_DATE", "NUM_VALUE")
values (:p1, :p2, :p3)
```

As you can see, EF is adding a namespace "dbo" before my table name and obviously oracle has no idea what "dbo" is.

How to remove the namespace prefix?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that perhaps EF thinks that maybe this is a SQL Server connection? Isn't dbo the standard database owner in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it is. But still, how to remove that?